# C#: Build 3D-Array and fill it with data

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

The code I tried so far below:

```
private static List<List<List<int>>> threeDArrayToThreeDList(int [,,] letters) {
    // 3d-array to 3d-list
    List<List<List<int>>> letterslist = new List<List<List<int>>>();
    List<List<int>> sublist = new List<List<int>> ();
    List<int> subsublist = new List<int> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        letterslist.Add (sublist);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            letterslist[i].Add (subsublist);
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                Console.WriteLine (letterslist [i][j][k]); // Element not found         
                Console.WriteLine (letters [i,j,k]);
                letterslist [i] [j] [k] = letters [i,j,k];
            }
        }
    }
    return letterslist;
}
```

Why letterslist [i][j][k] isn't found?

Comment: Do you ensure that for example letterslist[3] is NOT null ? I don't see the code that creates lists instances for every parent location.

Comment: `Why letterslist [i][j][k]  isn't found?` because `subsublist` is empty.

Comment: subsublist is created, but empty. Therefore, letterslist [0][0][0] will trigger an exception.

Comment: Also note that you are filling `sublist` with the *same* instance of `subsublist` and `letterlist` with the *same* instance of `sublist`.

Comment: @Matt Burland But why letterslist [i] [j] [k] = letters [i,j,k]; also doesn't work?

Comment: @kame: Because *your list is empty*. You can't access `letterslist[0][0][0]` because `letterslist[0][0].Count == 0`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan:  That will still throw since `letterslist [i] [j] [k] ` is still out of bounds.

Comment: @kame You should be careful with what "solution" you end up using. Since you decided to replace your selected answer, I must warn you that without the change outlined in my answer your code will not work, and Mikhail's answer will only solve your exception, but not your data structure & arrays construction.

Comment: @Amit The code is working with Mikhails answer!

Comment: @kame are you sure? try to use his code without the modifications in my answer (keep all the `new List<...>` at the top of the function), and use an input that has no recurring values (make sure every item in the 3d array is different). I doubt you'll see matching prints in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You need to create a list for each "index". You're code only creates 3 lists altogether.

Here's how it should work:

```
private static List<List<List<int>>> threeDArrayToThreeDList(int [,,] letters) {
    // 3d-array to 3d-list
    List<List<List<int>>> letterslist = new List<List<List<int>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        letterslist.Add (new List<List<int>> ());
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            letterslist[i].Add (new List<int> ());
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                Console.WriteLine (letters [i,j,k]);
                letterslist [i] [j].Add(letters [i,j,k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return letterslist;
}
```

Comment: And using `Array.GetLength` would probably be better than hard-coding those lengths.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - is that a hint? I have to be honest... Posting from mobile :-) please correct what you see (the answer is useful to demonstrate the correct solution even if it's not accurate, but should be fixed as needed)

Comment: And regarding length... Well, I'm not assuming anything regarding what the code should do (for example, what if the intention really is to only run to 2 in each depth, regardless of actual bounds?)

Comment: I need a break. Too much input now. :) The array is much larger. I wonder because letterslist[i][j].Add(...) looks like a two-dimensional array!?!?!?!?

Comment: This adds elements to the 3rd dimensions, much like list.add(..) adds elements to the 1st

Comment: Hello Amit again. I only difference in our code examples is letterslist [i] [j].Add(letters [i,j,k]);

Answer (score 0):

This because the letterslist [i][j] list has no elements in it.
Add an element to it, and it will get you through the line that causes the exception.

Change the code in the innermost loop as follows:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    letterslist[i][j].Add (letters[i, j, k]);
    Console.WriteLine(letterslist[i][j][k]); // Should work fine
    Console.WriteLine(letters[i, j, k]);
}
```

Comment: Not only is this answer lacking crucial information as included in my answer, it is incorrect at it's current state. On iterations after i = 0 & j = 0, the 2 console outputs won't match. The only "correct" information in this answer is that trying to "read" letterlist[i][j][k] before adding elements is wrong. (Also that could be added as a comment as it contributes nothing important that's not included in my answer)